# Squid and proxychains setup

Tags: proxy, tor, squid, privoxy

I'm having trouble getting squid to use proxychains proxy list which includes tor.
is there a way i can make squid talk to proxychains

```
Privoxy Config:
listen-address 127.0.0.1:8118
listen-address [::1]:8118
forward-socks5t / 127.0.0.1:9050
Proxychains Config:
dynamic_chain
proxy_dns
tcp_read_time_out 15000
tcp_connect_time_out 8000

[ProxyList]
socks4 127.0.0.1 9050
# Add more proxies here

Tor Config:
SocksPort 127.0.0.1:9050 IsolateClientAddr IsolateSOCKSAuth IsolateClientProtocol
EntryNodes {gb} StrictNodes 1
ExitNodes {gb} StrictNodes 1
Log notice file /var/log/tor/notices.log
Log debug file /var/log/tor/debug.log
Squid config 
cache_peer 127.0.0.1 parent 8118 0 no-query default
auth_param basic program /usr/lib/squid/basic_ncsa_auth /etc/squid/passwd
acl auth_users proxy_auth REQUIRED
acl privoxy_peer dst 127.0.0.1/32
acl SSL_ports port 443
acl Safe_ports port 80
acl CONNECT method CONNECT
http_access allow auth_users
http_access allow privoxy_peer
never_direct allow privoxy_peer
http_access deny all
dns_v4_first on
forwarded_for delete
via off
http_access deny !Safe_ports
http_access deny CONNECT !SSL_ports
http_access deny manager
http_access allow localhost
http_access deny all
http_port 45633
refresh_pattern ^ftp: 1440 20% 10080
refresh_pattern ^gopher: 1440 0% 1440
refresh_pattern -i (/cgi-bin/|\?) 0 0% 0
refresh_pattern \/(Packages|Sources)(|\.bz2|\.gz|\.xz)$ 0 0% 0 refresh-ims
refresh_pattern \/Release(|\.gpg)$ 0 0% 0 refresh-ims
refresh_pattern \/InRelease$ 0 0% 0 refresh-ims
refresh_pattern \/(Translation-.*)(|\.bz2|\.gz|\.xz)$ 0 0% 0 refresh-ims
refresh_pattern . 0 20% 4320
include /etc/squid/conf.d/*
```